# how do you insert the data in file into table in php

Tags: php

I am writing a php script that will use ssh to login to a server, get the latest 30 lines ina file and insert the data into the table:

system.out file looks like this, delimited by space:

```
2014-05-21-16.30.20 20
2014-05-21-16.31.20 10
2014-05-21-16.32.20 30
2014-05-21-16.33.20 50
2014-05-21-16.34.20 10
2014-05-21-16.35.20 50
2014-05-21-16.36.20 60
```

This is my script. I have three fields in my table: DATE, SERVER, IO. I capture DATE and IO from the output of the above file and SERVER from the servers array:

```
<?php
chdir('c:/php');

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$servers=array('ServerA','ServerB);
foreach ($servers as &$value1) {

    $server=$value1.".example.net";
    ##echo "$server\n";
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
        if (!$ssh->login('user', 'passwd')) {

            continue;
            ##exit('Login Failed');
        }
        $file_name="/system.out";
        $line= $ssh->exec("tail -30 file_name");
        $rawLines = explode("\n", $line);
        $lines = array();
    foreach($rawLines as $rawLine){
        $rawLine = trim($rawLine);
        $parts = explode(" ", $rawLine); 
        $lines[] = $parts;
     $conn=odbc_connect('odbc_id','user','passd');
        if (!$conn)
        {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
        foreach ($lines as $value) {
        $value[0] = '\''.$value[0] .'\'';
        $value[0]='to_date('.$value[0].','.'\'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS\')';
            $new_value = array();
            $new_value[0]=$value[0];
            $new_value[1]="'".$value1."'";
            $new_value[2]=$value[1].')';
            $sql="insert into DB_IO T (T.\"DATE\", T.SERVER, T.IO) VALUES (";
            //print($sql."\n");
            $my_array= implode(",", $new_value);
            print($my_array."\n");
            $sql = $sql.$my_array;
            echo($sql."\n");

            $prepare = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
            $rs=odbc_execute($prepare);
        }
    }
}
odbc_close($conn);
exit;
?>
```

Looks like this script is trying to insert to the same line multiple times. I need to try to insert one line one time. Any ideas, what am I doing wrong here? I need help here.

Comment: errors in code above, as shown by the colours

Comment: ^--« ...right here `('ServerA','SeverB)` unless that's just a typo.

Comment: your edit left he error in.

Comment: @Dagon, I see your point. Even after correcting the comments, still not working. I get file_name: No such file or directory.

Comment: @Dagon, why this script trying to insert the same line twice?